# Rails 3 - jquery within assets/javascripts is not running on page load

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've just set up rails, I've got my custom index page set up, got my CSS working from assets/stylesheets, and my javascript is working from assets/javascripts.

jQuery is also working if I put it within 'script' tags in my index.html, or if I run some random jQuery code from the Firebug console.

However, no Jquery code is executed on page load from within my js file in assets/javascripts. Any idea why?

I suspect it might have something to do with the order that my page is loading the different files, but I can't see anywhere that I can check or fix this.

I've got this within my application.js -

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

I've got this within the head of my layouts file, if it's relevent-

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

This is the output of my server log on page load -

```
Started GET "/" for 192.168.2.3 at Sat May 19 15:58:47 +0100 2012
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Rendered home/index.html within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Compiled application.js  (8ms)  (pid 15001)
Completed 200 OK in 158ms (Views: 157.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 192.168.2.3 at Sat May 19 15:58:51 +0100   2012
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 192.168.2.3 at Sat May 19 15:58:51 +0100 2012
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/home.js?body=1" for 192.168.2.3 at Sat May 19 15:58:51 +0100 2012
Served asset /home.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 192.168.2.3 at Sat May 19 15:58:51 +0100 2012
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (22ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 192.168.2.3 at Sat May 19 15:58:51 +0100 2012
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/home.css?body=1" for 192.168.2.3 at Sat May 19 15:58:51 +0100 2012
Served asset /home.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```

I'm not getting any errors in Firebug, or anything that suggests it's not working.

Comment: what jquery code you tried to execute from file?

Comment: Within "/assets/home.js" I've tried - 
`$('#output').append("test")`

and tried random things like - 
`dave = $('#output').html()`
and then trying to alert dave etc.

Just doesn't run the jQuery, but it will execute any standard javascript I put in there.

Comment: Once the code has been rendered it looks like this -
`(function() {
  var dave;

  alert("gyugyugyug");

  dave = $('#output').html();

}).call(this);`

Comment: Have you tried to put jQuery code into $(function{...}); ?